# python functions refactoring

Tags: python, refactoring

I wrote the two functions below:

```
def dataproc_first_job (self,task_id, app,job):
    return DataProcSparkOperator(
    task_id=task_id,
    dataproc_spark_jars=self.jar,
    cluster_name=self.cluster,
    main_class=self.main_name,
    dataproc_spark_properties={
        'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s    -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s'  % (app, job) },
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
)
```

---

```
def dataproc_second_job (self,task_id, app,job,prefix,dataset):
    return DataProcSparkOperator(
    task_id=task_id,
    dataproc_spark_jars=self.jar,
    cluster_name=self.cluster,
    main_class=self.main_name,
    dataproc_spark_properties={
        'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s      -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s   -DTrm.Options.prefix=%s   -DTrm.Metadata.outputBase=%s'   %(app,  domain, job, prefix, dataset) },
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )
```

My aim is to refactor the python code to just use one function instead of two. I thought about using decorators . I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Any ideas how to cope with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need decorators. I'd do it this way:

```
def dataproc_first_job (self, task_id, app, job, prefix=None, dataset=None):
    if prefix is None or dataset is None:
        dataproc_spark_properties={
            'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s -DTrm.Options.prefix=%s -DTrm.Metadata.outputBase=%s' %(app,domain, job, prefix, dataset)
        }
    else:
        dataproc_spark_properties={
            'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s' % (app, job)
        }
    return DataProcSparkOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        dataproc_spark_jars=self.jar,
        cluster_name=self.cluster,
        main_class=self.main_name,
        dataproc_spark_properties,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use default arguments to the function:

```
def dataproc_job(self, task_id, app, job, prefix=None, dataset=None):
    if prefix is not None and dataset is not None:
        props={
            'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s -DTrm.Options.prefix=%s -DTrm.Metadata.outputBase=%s' %(app, domain, job, prefix, dataset)
        }
    else:
        props={
        'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s' % (app, job)
        }

    return DataProcSparkOperator( ... ) # Build your object as normal
```

Or if there are potentially more arguments to come, you can use `kwargs`:

```
def dataproc_job(self, task_id, app, job, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["prefix"] is not None and kwargs["dataset"] is not None:
        props={
            'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s -DTrm.Options.prefix=%s -DTrm.Metadata.outputBase=%s' %(app, domain, job, kwargs["prefix"], kwargs["dataset"])
        }
    else:
        props={
        'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions': '-DAppConfig.appName=%s -DTrmRaw.Options.jobName=%s' % (app, job)
        }

    return DataProcSparkOperator( ... ) # Build your object as normal
```

At this stage, either way I would refactor again and extract the properties builder section as a seperate function:

```
def get_dataproc_spark_properties(prefix=None, dataset=None):
    if prefix is not None and dataset is not None:
    # etc...
    #Build and return the properties string
```

or

```
def get_dataproc_spark_properties(**kwargs):
    if kwargs["prefix"] is not None and kwargs["dataset"] is not None:
    # etc...
    #Build and return the properties string
```

And then call this function in your `dataproc_job` function:

```
def dataproc_job(self, task_id, app, job, prefix=None, dataset=None):
    props = get_dataproc_spark_properties(prefix, dataset)
```

or

```
def dataproc_job(self, task_id, app, job, **kwargs):
    props = get_dataproc_spark_properties(**kwargs)
```